# How to display font styles on Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cross-browser

I am having a problem where the following code will display the desired result in `Microsoft Edge` but will not display the correct result in `Chrome`  or any other browser. The reason `Edge` cannot be used  is our program must be run on a `raspberry pi.`

We have tried multiple browsers and none will display our data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sensor Data</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function print() {
fetch("test.txt")
  .then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
  var num = parseInt(text);
   document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = num;
  if(num>250){
   console.log(num);
   document.body.style.color = "green";
 }
  else
  {
  console.log(num);
  document.body.style.color = "red";
}
 })
  }
  setInterval(print, 1000);
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>

 <h1>Range: <span id="myText"></span></h1>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Our result should display the data from the text file in the color decided based on the data form the text file. Such as green for 251 and above and red for 250 and below.

Comment: "we have tried multiple browsers and none will display our data" Do you mean to say that no data is displaying at all, or that it is displayed just without the correct color?   Are you encountering any errors when running the script?

Comment: In edge the correct color and data will display but in chrome and other browsers Range will display but no data or color will be present

Comment: Do you have some examples of the file contents when this happens?  Tough to solve an edge case without knowing how to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

your myFunction is never declared.  Not sure where fetch would grab a file on stackoverflow so I modified your code to not use.  I don't think that's causing your problem. This seems to work, on chrome and firefox.  Is this not what you want?

```js
function print() {

  var num = 250;
  a = document.getElementById("myText1");
  b = document.getElementById("myText2");
  
  document.getElementById("myText1").innerHTML = num;
  document.getElementById("myText2").innerHTML = num;
  if(num>250){
   console.log(num);
   a.style.color = "green";
   b.style.color = "red";
  }else{
   console.log(num);
   b.style.color = "green";
   a.style.color = "red";
}
 
  }
  print();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sensor Data</title>

  
 </head>

 <body>

 <h1>Range: <span id="myText1"></span></h1>
 <h1>Range: <span id="myText2"></span></h1>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: When attempting to use the given code I was unable to display any data on the browser. I did remove the "MyFunction" onload feature with the same result.

Comment: did you check console.log?  are you getting any errors? If not, you need to create a snippet to shows us whats going on

Comment: I am getting a failed to fetch error and it says the URL scheme must be "http or https" for CORS request